# How is the complexity of the relationship between pattern and category quantified?

Tags: classification

Lets say you have a class $C$ of binary strings $s$, and each string corresponds to one of $n$ categories. How do you quantify the complexity of the relationship between the sequence of bits in $s$ and the categorization of $s$.

For example, Imagine your strings are 6 bits long, $n=2$, and the first bit is the only one that has any bearing on categorization. That would be pretty simple.

On the other hand, you could have cases where the relationship is described by a formula, eg:

$\operatorname{Category} =x_5$XOR$x_4$XOR$x_3$XOR$x_2$XOR$x_1$XOR$x_0$

or you could have a case where arbitrary rules indicate the category, eg: "any string of the form -101-- falls into the category 6, unless $x_0$ is true"

In any case, how do you quantify the complexity of the correspondence between pattern and category.